# Two arrays in a for-loop issue

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I just finished The C Programming Language exercise 1-13 wherein I am to make a program to print a horizontal histogram or a vertical histogram. (I made the horizontal version)

But there is a problem I encountered with the code below: (Let's call this code #1)

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    ncc[i] = 0;
    nlc[i] = 0;
```

I fixed the code by doing so: (Let's call this code #2)

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    ncc[i] = 0; 
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    nlc[i] = 0;
```

There are two arrays: `ncc` is an array that counts capital letters and `nlc` is an array that counts small letters.

The code #1 I provided you is somewhat buggy to array `nlc` and to prove that, I'll demonstrate to you how I ran it and will only show you the small letter histogram portion of the program since that's the focus of this issue.

```
PS <..LOC..> cc histogram-0.c
PS <..LOC..> ./a
i am an arms dealer fitting you with weapons in the form of words
                  SMALL LETTER AND LETTER COUNTS
a | ***** (05)
b | *********************************************************... (It's infinite)
```

My question is: **Why do 2 arrays in 1 for loop not work (code #1) while 1 array works for 1 loop? (code #2)**

Comment: Because `nlc[i] = 0` isn't a part of the `for` loop in the first case.  When in doubt, __use braces__.  Put the two line in `{}`.

Comment: @devnull Pedant...you mean braces?

Comment: @devnull You mean like `ncc[i] = (nlc[i] = 0);`? I tested that and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your code is as presented above, it should be noted that for-loops without braces only work if there is only one statement. As such, your first example will only set for array ncc, while your second example works.

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i){
 ncc[i] = 0;
 nlc[i] = 0;
}
```

^ As above should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    ncc[i] = 0; // part of for loop
    nlc[i] = 0; //outside for loop
```

As nlc[i]=0 is outside for loop, only i=27 will be zero and other values in array will be garbage.

According to semantics of c language if no brackets are specified in loops only one line is considered part of loop.

Better way to initialize all of elements to zero is

```
int ncc[size]={0},nlc[size]={0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    ncc[i] = 0;
    nlc[i] = 0;
```

It should be this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
    {
    ncc[i] = 0;
    nlc[i] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: How could I not realize that I forgot to use braces all this time? I think I need a rest to clear my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make this a comment but I have insufficient reputation... but basically if you're new to programming I recommend to always use braces to make it absolutely clear where scopes start and end.

It usually makes code more readable, has no effect on performance in a compiled language, and removes ambiguity.